# Xcode 7.3 ad hoc distribution launches on some iOS devices not others

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I have distributed a an ad hoc version of my `iPad` app to several users and have found that it will launch on some iPads but not others (it installs on all). So far, it has launched successfully on an iPad Mini (1st gen) and an `iPad` (4th gen). It will not launch on an `iPad Air` or an `iPad Air 2`.

I know that the UDIDs are correct and present in the provisioning profile. I believe all devices are running `iOS 9.3`. The deployment target is 8.0. There are no Capabilities included. There are two static libraries included via sub-projects (libpd and OpenFrameworks). I've just asked one user to send me a crash log, which I've not yet seen, but if the app won't launch, there might not be any info in the crash log anyway.

Can anyone offer me any hints?

Comment: You need the crash logs to symbolicate. This is the only way to track down the crash. Other useful information for yourself might be the iOS version and if it is a clean install or an upgrade to an existing installed app.

Comment: @Robotic Cat what exactly are the issues related to clean install vs upgrade? If I send a new ipa file, and the installation shows that it has an updated icon name, what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Example: Upgrade installs could have an issue where you could have previously saved data in User Defaults and attempted to read the wrong data back or failed to account for an upgrade to a Core Data model (or other storage solution) so when the app attempts to read / open your database it crashes. New installs will not have this issue but may other issues such as crashing when attempting to open a non-existing database.

Comment: Evaluate which all users are getting crash is it all new user or all update user or mix of both. Also iPad Air always have some API issues, i have encountered them in past where everything works on other devices but iPad Air will cause issue.

Comment: @Arun The app has never launched for these two iPad Air users, so in that sense they have been all new users. I've tried sending them updates with potential fixes. In one case, I instructed the user to delete the old app before installing. Can you say more about the iPad Air issues?

Comment: @Robotic As I've just noted, this problem has been there from the get-go with the iPad Air users. I'm not explicitly accessing or writing any data (at present the app just runs a graphics procedure). Would there be any saving of data that would occur in any case?

Comment: @RonH: If you've checked all the code in the initial methods & haven't found anything obvious then you need a symbolicated crash log to track this down. When you do have a symbolicated crash log then post a new question with that log. In the meantime I don't think anyone can help you so I would close this question.

Comment: @Robotic I have a crash log, though not yet symbolicated. The exception is this: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
From what I've read, it seems this indicates that a deallocated object is being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the provisioning profile actually being used by Xcode is the current version with those devices in it, I would recommend running your app source code through Deploymate and see if it finds problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, dgatwood. Deploymate says 0 problems found.